# Hibernate Criteria API orderBy and Embedded element

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, embeddable

Lets say I have a `Report` entity. Inside it there is `@Embeddable ReportPeriod` which has `Integer month` and `Integer year` fields. When i try to sort my `Report report` by its `ReportPeriod reportPeriod` it sorts `report` by `month` and `year`. How to change the order of sort (`year` and then `month`). Can this be solved by any of the annotations?

Comment: Please make you question more clear: When do you want to sort, and how? - By an Criteria Api Query, or by Collections.sort?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to load several reports by hibernate criteria and sort them by its embebedded month and year?

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Report.class);
crit.addOrder(Order.asc("reportPeriod.year"));
crit.addOrder(Order.asc("reportPeriod.month"));
...=crit.list();
```

But I am not 100% sure if Order can be applied to an @Embeddable, but is expect it.